# Кириллица отображается некорректно на странице

Tags: php, oracle

1. Есть БД oracle 11.2g, NLS_LANG = American_America.CL8MSWIN1251.
2. php 5.3 (Подключаюсь к БД через PDO, charset=CL8MSWIN1251)
3. WebServer nginx 1.8.0
4. ОС - Oracle Linux 6

При извлечении данных русский текст в браузере отображается знаками вопроса
Подскажите, как можно исправить?

При этом в sqlplus русский текст отображается правильно, если выполнить в консоли как php index.php, русский текст отображается правильно, проблема только с выводом русского из БД в браузер.

locale выдает ru_RU.utf-8

Кодировку в браузере выставлял различную - никакого эффекта - вместо русского текста знаки вопросов. Интересный момент: в php коде выставлял meta charset  и utf-8 и windows-1251 при этом в терминале в обоих случаях кириллица отображалась корректно

Comment: Вы пробуете в текстовой консоли Windows? Если так, то результат странный, т.к. там родная кодировка CP866, а вы получаете данные в MSWIN1251. По личному опыту в тестах в консоли приходилось переключать NLS_LANG на досовую кодовую страницу.

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно браузер считает, что кодировка страницы `UTF-8`, а ваши данные в `WINDOWS-1251`. Проверить можно так: попробуйте принудительно указать браузеру разные кодировки и смотрите результат. В Chrome это пункт меню `More tools/Encoding`.

Попробуйте одно из двух:

- Указать на странице кодировку как у данных;
- Применить кодировку соединения с БД как на странице.